# About finite automaton's size and number of states

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, dfa

I'm trying to figure out finite automaton's size and number of it's states.

Consider there is `L = {0,1}*1{0,1}^n`.

I want to show,

1. L can be accepted by an unambiguous finite automaton of size O(n)
2. Any deterministic ε-free normal-form finite automaton accepting L must have at least 2^n states.

At first, I tried to draw automaton for L. However I'm not able to prove it's size and how many states it has. Really need help.

Answer (score 0):

The decisive feature of the language is that all words have a 1 at the position n+1 before the end. The obvious tactics is to start a counter, whenever you read a 1. When the counter reaches n you

- delete it, if the word's end has not yet been reached, i.e. your 1 was not the one at the decisive position
- accept, if the word's end has been reached.

Every one of the possible different situations of the up to n counters is distinct, i.e. will lead to acceptance with a different set of suffixes. Therefore in the deterministic automaton you need at least one distinct state for each of the situations. Now count...

For part 1, with non-determinism you just guess for any 1 that it is the decisive one, count to n and see if you are at the word's end. One of the guesses will be the correct one (if the word is in the language). For counting to n you need about n states.